# How to send a response back to client using websockets in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am using the Serverless Framework to deploy a WebSocket app to AWS Lambda.

I need to make it send a response back to the client when it hits a WebSocket route.

Here is my handler:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

module.exports.websocketHandler = async (event, _) => {
  const {
    requestContext: { routeKey }
  } = event;

  switch (routeKey) {
    case "$connect":
      // ....
      break;

    case "$disconnect":
      // ....
      break;

    case "getBot":
      const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
      const postData = body.data;
      const params = {
        ConnectionId: event.requestContext.connectionId,
        Data: JSON.stringify(postData)
      };

      postMessage(params, event);
      break;

    case "$default":
    default:
      return { statusCode: 200 };
  }

  return { statusCode: 200 };
};

const postMessage = async (data, event) => {
  try {
    const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
      apiVersion: "2018-11-29",
      `https://${event.requestContext.domainName}/${event.requestContext.stage}`
    });

    await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(data).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

It just responds back with whatever was sent. I am using `wscat` tool to connect to the WebSocket.

```
wscat -c wss://{API-ID}.execute-api.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/dev
{"action": "getBot", "data": "Hello world"}
```

I have tried testing it offline, and it works just fine. And when deployed, I can connect to it, but whenever I try to send the action to getBot, I get no response.

Comment: The way you're using it (at least in this example), you'd be better off with a REST api, since you're literally just responding when the client sends you a request. I don't know much about this stuff but I use a websocket api and it works perfectly with a lambda posting a message to registered connection ids, but I never do it within a response to the client's message - not sure if that even works.

Comment: I have used this example of code for the sake of simplicity and debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my lambda, It was in a custom VPC which resulted in lambda not getting internet access.

I fixed this by adding additional subnets with a NAT Gateway in AWS.

Comment: but why do you need internet access, if you send the data to your api-gateway? I mean if you receive a message , then you can send back results to the sender. then you use your managemenapi apigateawy don't you?

Answer (score 0):

For others coming to this question, you need to do a few things:

1. Create a WebSocket API with the **API Gateway**.
2. Create **route keys** for each WS event you need to handle.
3. Simultaneously while creating route keys (or before), create Lambda functions for each WS event. **Connect your given Lambda function to the WS API route**. (Be sure to deploy your Lambda functions)
4. Ensure your **permissions** are setup correctly for each Lambda function (make sure the API Gateway can access them).
5. **Deploy your WS API from the API Gateway**. Use the wss://[...] URL to connect via a client.

Helpful docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-develop.html

Enjoy!